# How to create an instance from string name?

Tags: reflection, types, instantiation, haxe

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666527/haxe-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string-name), but I'm looking for a Haxe 3.0 solution. I'm looking to instantiate a class based on a a string (from my data file).

As far as I can tell this is correct. However, I get a runtime error

```
[Fault] exception, information=No such constructor npc.NPC_Squid
Fault, createEnum() at Type.hx:166
```

**The Haxe 3 Code:**

```
var e = haxe.macro.Expr.ExprDef;            
var instance :Dynamic = e.createByName( "npc." +  data.character, [] );
    //....
```

**My class:**

```
package npc;

import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import openfl.Assets;

class NPC_Squid extends Sprite
{   
    public function new()
    {
        super();
        addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        addEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemoved);

    }
//....
```

My packages seem correct. Any ideas as to why it can't find the constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an instance of a class from a string name in Haxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666527/create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string-name-in-haxe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need this:

```
 var myInstance = Type.createInstance(Type.resolveClass("mypackage.MyClass"));
```

Note if you use [dead-code elimination](http://haxe.org/doc/compiler#compilation-options), you should import/reference MyClass somewhere.
I mostly create a function *forceCompile* in my Main class for such things:

```
 public static function main() 
 {
    forceCompile();

    // Wind up all your stuff
 }

 public static function forceCompile()
 {
      MyClass;
 }
```

Comment: I tried the forced reference trick... no luck. Also, the Type.createInstance does not exist in HaXe 3.0. That's why i'm using the macro createByName(...); It looks like it is trying to resolve the constructor though (and not finding it).

Comment: Type.createInstance() has not been removed in Haxe 3 and should work. Possible reasons for the constructor not to be found are DCE (in that case just add @:keep) or that the type is not imported anywhere in your project.

Comment: ooooooh. Haha, I had accidentally auto-imported haxe.macro.Type which is why it was saying these functions do not exist!

Answer (score 1):

In my Haxe 3 project, I use:

```
var easing: IEasing = Type.createEmptyInstance(Type.resolveClass("motion.easing." + easingType + easingStyle));
```

And it worked perfectly. One important precision: you need to import all the class that can be created this way. I imported all my motion.easing package to be sure.

You can see the full example [here](https://github.com/Knowledge-Players/grar/blob/master/com/knowledgeplayers/grar/display/TweenManager.hx)

Comment: ooooooh. Haha, I had accidentally auto-imported haxe.macro.Type which is why it was saying these functions do not exist!

Comment: I ended up needing params so I went with createInstance